# Is it possible to pay per request on AWS, like Google App engine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting

Can I host a website on AWS, and pay per request, and not per instance (like Google App Engine?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about paying for things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

you can host your website on [S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html) (provided it has static contents). But if you hosts it on an AWS instance, you have to pay for the instance.